# input field validation on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have four text field in reactjs forms.when i validated the forms and provide only one text field then different toast error msg didn't popup .it doesnot iterates over text field values?

```
let check_fields = [
            {
                "name": "productname",
                "msg":"please enter Name"
            },
            {
                "name": "categoryName",
                "msg":"please enter categoryName"
            },
            {
                "name": "price",
                "msg":"please enter amount"
            },
{
                "name": "colour",
                "msg":"please enter colour"
            },
          
        ]
        for(let checks in check_fields){
         
            let _checks = check_fields[checks]
            if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "" && undefined ) {
                toast.error(_checks["msg"])
                return false
            }
            return true         
        }
```

Comment: Since check_fields is an array, it should be a for of loop, not for in loop

Answer (score 0):

you are validating against two conditions `if(theInputField == "" && undefined)` so both conditions have to be true and then the  error message will kick off try or `||` also remove the === , == is enough
**try this :-**

```
for(let checks in check_fields){
         
            let _checks = check_fields[checks]
            if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] == "" || undefined ) {
                toast.error(_checks["msg"])
                return false
            }
            return true         
        }
```

**or simply remove the undefined condition like this : -**

```
for(let checks in check_fields){
         
            let _checks = check_fields[checks]
            if (fieldValues[_checks["name"]] === "") {
                toast.error(_checks["msg"])
                return false
            }
            return true         
        }
```